# VS2012 using 3D models dilemma

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, model, 3d, directx

I'm having problems understanding the the usage of VS2012's 3D features in a project. I'm current building a 3D project using DirectX (Direct3D) and want display a simple 3D object (teapot) for starters. I understand the usage of the shadergraph which is of great help, but when it comes to loading an FBX model, is there an alternative to using the Autodesk FBX SDK built in or am I just stuck with it (FBXSDK)?

Generally, is there anything in VS2012 for C++ similar in nature to how XNA uses it's content pipeline to simplify loading and working with models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definitely need to manage the translation from the format of your model files to the typical D3D mesh/meshpart arrangement.  You can get sometimes find models in the old .x format, which corresponds to a Direct3D model. [This page](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/3d_models.html) has some good reference for loading .x files and also links to exporters for maya and max.

OTOH If your source data is in fbx, use the fbx sdk; it's just simpler than any alternative way to get fbx data. You'll need some library for importing 3d models and although they're all limited in different ways FBX has the advantage of being supported by the widest variety of DCC apps. There are text and binary versions of the FBX format, so if you're interested in manual debugging you can use the text based version to make it easier to crosscheck your results.  [This sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) discusses using the FBX SDK with DirectX 11 - although it is in the context of vs 2010, there may be issues moving to VS 2012.

If you go with another intermediate format you should look for one supported by the 3d tool you'll be using or the model vendor you are buying from.  [Collada](https://collada.org/) is the most widely available interchange format, and it's based on XML so you could probably implement your own loader -- however it's also notorious for complexity and inconsistent standards so I'd avoid it unless you have a compelling reason or a big trove f Collada format files.

If your needs are very simple and don't include animation, the [OBJ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) is widely available and easy to implement on your own -- however it does not support animation.

Answer (score 1):

> is there anything in VS2012 for C++ similar in nature to how XNA uses
>   it's content pipeline

As far as I know, there is no such thing. You will need your own solution, as always in native C++ world =). Probably, you can make use some of the modern [rendering engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines): Unity, OGRE, Irrlicht, Torque, etc.

> when it comes to loading an FBX model, is there an alternative to
>   using the Autodesk FBX SDK built in or am I just stuck with it
>   (FBXSDK)

As far as I know, [FBX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) is a closed proprietary format, so you stick with FBX SDK.

**Another ways (from gamedev view)**

1. FBX format is a terribly complicated and multifunctional. Typically, you don't need FBX to draw teapot. You don't even need FBX to create a good game.
2. to just draw teapot you, probably, better take another simple (or not so simple) [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats#3D_graphics), such as .obj, .dae or .3ds. You can load it using 3rd party library, such as [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) (which is just few lines of code) or roll out your own loader (which is not so hard either).
3. to draw some meaningful interactive "teapots world" you will also need to wrap them into some kind of scene: [scenegraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) is a common solution.
4. mid-size game labels typically crate their own format, converter and loader for it:

   - artists create models in their favorite 3D editor
   - then they convert it using converter: convert to custom binary .mesh format. This can be done via plugin for 3D editor or in small standalone app
   - in C++ app, programmers just load .mesh, deserialize to structs and classes and use it.
5. serious game labels develop their own content pipelines: it can include multiple custom formats (static mesh, animated mesh, etc.), loaders (to load and stream content into app), 3ds max/Maya/Blender plugins, visual scene/level editors (to make artists happy). All content is created and managed by artists, so programmers don't need any integration of content to their IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2012 actually has it's own model processor now.

You can add different meshes to your project(I think that it natively supports .dae, .fbx, and .obj) and it'll spit out a ".cmo" model that's simple to parse.

The directX Toolkit also has pretty good support for loading the format, so if you're already using the DXTK, then I recommend seeing if the model loader meets your requirements.